# A program for test sorting algorithms

Tags: windows, algorithm, sorting

Anyone know any program where I can define an input collecion and I can visualize the sorting algorithm (bubble, quick, shell, etc) step by step

Thus some

```
1th iteration result: [3, 5, 7, 1, 8, 9]
2th iteration result: [3, 5, 1, 7, 8, 9]
3th iteration result: [3, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9]
4th iteration result: [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
5th iteration result: [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
 
Final result: [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: You can always write one -- would be a good way to develop an understanding of the various algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good applet: http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~kirk/cs1501/animations/Sort2.html
or just look Google for `sorting applet`

In the next link is also good - you can enter your data : http://www.brian-borowski.com/Software/Sorting/

Comment: thanks, i still looking , that applet is good but u can't define costum data

Answer (score 5):

Nothing can explain different sorting algorithms better than this Hungarian folk dance group:

[Bubble-sort](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyZQPjUT5B4)

[Quick-sort](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDgvnbUIqT4)

[Select-sort](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ns4TPTC8whw)

[Merge-sort](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaqR3G_NVoo)

[Shell-sort](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmPA7zE8mx0)

But if you prefer a bit more formal approach I recommend you this site:

http://www.bluffton.edu/~nesterd/java/SortingDemo.html

You can choose different sorting algorithms, number and type of elements to sort and also different data sequences: random, ordered, reversed etc. You can't enter your own data there but I don't think that not using your own sequence of numbers could hinder the ability to understand the concept :)

Comment: +1 Completely ridiculous ... led me [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AR2KWYEpzQc&list=PLC79D6CCBB2C7ED13).

Comment: That's the right way to learn. You never forget bubble sort after watching a video like this.